# Why do statements after return change the return value?

Tags: c++

C++ returns invalid value in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int f(){
    vector< int * > v[2];
    return 1;
    v[1].push_back(NULL);
}

int main(){
    cout << f();
}
```

The output is:

```
205960
```

When I commnet line after return, it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int f(){
    vector< int * > v[2];
    return 1;
    //v[1].push_back(NULL);
}

int main(){
    cout << f();
}
```

The output is:

```
1
```

I am using code::blocks with mingw32-g++.exe compiler. The mingw version is: gcc version 4.4.1 (TDM-2 mingw32).

Comment: So it actually is affected by the code line AFTER the return? Strange.

Comment: sinni800, yes, result of programm changes after I comment line after return.

Comment: Why do you have code that follows an unconditional return?

Comment: couldn't reproduce, sounds like a bug.

Comment: This is minimized version of my original code, but it also behaves in the same strange  way.

Comment: The subject was very unspecific (didn't specify the return call at all) and also imprecise (205960 is invalid, but not correct).

Comment: this works as expected: http://ideone.com/fV8Oa
what compiler are you using?

Comment: Please post the exact version of the compiler you are using plus all relevant options/optimization you are using when compiling that code.

Comment: mingw version is:
gcc version 4.4.1 (TDM-2 mingw32)  and linker options: -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL

Comment: I only have 4.5, 4.6 and 4.1 handy and couldn't reproduce with either.

Comment: (and neither of my compilers is mingw32 either)

Comment: please write the complete code

Comment: Can't reproduce with gcc 4.4.5 on Debian.

Comment: This code is complete to reproduce this strange behavior. I and i tested it on 2 similar machines with code::block and same mingw compiler. Both produced same strange behavior.

Comment: Compile with -S and provide the assembly dump of that function.

Comment: +1 for CPP: Provide the assembler output please: `g++ -S -o prog.s prog.c -O2`

Comment: When I added -s -o -o2 options to compiler strange behavior disapiered

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your compiler has a bug. Fortunately, it is also obsolete. You should upgrade — G++ is up to version 4.6.2, which also implements much of C++11, which is *very* useful.

If you choose to stick with an older compiler, that is also a decision to accept its flaws.

**Edit:** If you are really stuck with 4.4 (for example due to a PHB), that series *is* still maintained. You can upgrade to GCC 4.4.6, released just this past April.

Comment: have you tested that compiler with the example given?

Comment: This is the most plausible answer, +1. If the bug really exists (not to doubt the OP, but I failed to reproduce it).

Comment: @Roman: We should all take it on faith that OP's machine did what he says it did. How does reproducibility matter?

Comment: You claim the compiler has the bug.. You must have evidence.

Comment: Don't recommend non-release versions please. For instance, a recent 4.7 snapshot fails horribly when compiling Boost.regex. Just wait for the stable releases.

Comment: @Roman: The evidence is the OP's assertion. Assume he tells the truth, reach a conclusion. Valid, non-executed code causes an invalid result from execution. The language implementation must be faulty.